# Insert attributes on-the-fly to an "a" tag

Tags: xslt, diazo

I need to modify on-the-fly the "content" of all the "a" tags present in a specific div (#navigation).

Is there a diazo rule or xslt pattern?

Thank's
Vito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following demonstrates adding an attribute (in this case `target`) to each of the `a` tags that are child elements under an element with the id of `navigation` (so corresponding to `#navigation` in CSS). All content and other attributes from the original tags are maintained (although order may not be - though this shouldn't be an issue).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo"
       xmlns:css="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo/css"
       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <after css:theme="#target" css:content="#navigation" />

    <xsl:template match="*[@id='navigation']//a">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</rules>
```

Adjust the `match` condition accordingly with additional conditions if you want to match specific `a` tags.  The `xsl:template` will be executed after all standard Diazo rules, so ensure that you adjust the `match` condition accordingly if you happen to change the structure of where the `a` tags are in your resulting document.

This was extended an example in the official Diazo documentation at http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/recipes/adding-an-attribute/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean.
If you want to create an XSLT that copies everything but tweak only the "a" elements inside the  div id='navigation' you should do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="-1">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//div[@id='navigation']//a">
   <a>
       <xsl:attribute name='href'>
           <xsl:value-of select='@href' />
       </xsl:attribute>
       <!-- Change your content here -->
   </a>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```